# SD can't mount and mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card dmesg error

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, mount, internal-sd

My android device (Samsung Galaxy S with cwm) stop mounting properly the internal SD card to /sdcard/ mountpoint: normal boot fails and cwm recovery says "Can't mount sdcard" while trying.

Through adb shell terminal, I've seen that mmc* devices are not recognized at all

```
shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/partitions                                         
major minor  #blocks  name

  31        0       7680 mtdblock0
  31        1       7680 mtdblock1
  31        2     256000 mtdblock2
  31        3      17920 mtdblock3
  31        4      12800 mtdblock4
  31        5      16384 mtdblock5
  31        6     176128 mtdblock6
  31        7      11264 mtdblock7


shell@android:/ $ dmesg | grep mmc                                             
<6>[    0.000000] sclk_mmc: source is mout_mpll (6), rate is 51307692
<6>[    0.000000] sclk_mmc: source is mout_mpll (6), rate is 47642857
<6>[    0.000000] sclk_mmc: source is mout_mpll (6), rate is 47642857
<6>[    0.000000] sclk_mmc: source is mout_mpll (6), rate is 47642857
<6>[    3.073948] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.0: clock source 0: hsmmc (133400000 Hz)
<6>[    3.074154] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.0: clock source 2: sclk_mmc (51307692 Hz)
<6>[    3.075282] mmc0: SDHCI controller on samsung-hsmmc [s3c-sdhci.0] using ADMA
<6>[    3.075468] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.1: clock source 0: hsmmc (133400000 Hz)
<6>[    3.075675] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.1: clock source 2: sclk_mmc (47642857 Hz)
<6>[    3.075966] mmc1: SDHCI controller on samsung-hsmmc [s3c-sdhci.1] using ADMA
<6>[    3.076208] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.2: clock source 0: hsmmc (133400000 Hz)
<6>[    3.076413] s3c-sdhci s3c-sdhci.2: clock source 2: sclk_mmc (47642857 Hz)
<6>[    3.076671] mmc2: SDHCI controller on samsung-hsmmc [s3c-sdhci.2] using ADMA
<3>[    4.682865] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card
<3>[    6.288432] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card
<3>[    7.897690] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card
<4>[    7.959521] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (50 bytes)
<4>[    7.971173] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
<4>[    8.009624] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
<6>[    8.022843] mmc1: new SDIO card at address 0001
<4>[    8.062894] bcmsdh_sdmmc: probe of mmc1:0001:3 failed with error -110
```

Is it an hardware problem or can I try to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card`

This means that the internal SD card has failed.

The common workaround for this is to install Android to an external SD card. I can't comment on the Samsung Galaxy S, but I am currently doing this for a Samsung Galaxy Tab using the following instructions: http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f606/internal-sdcard-damaged-1471227/

Hopefully you can find some instructions specific to your phone.